# problems by xslt hive off child-nodes in correct oder

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, transform, transformation

I've some problems by transforming my xml.
I'ld like to hive-off child-node in correct order.

### Current nesting of elements ( / nodes)

```
<span style="font-family: [Ohne];">
   <span style="font-family: qwe;">etu</span>
   <!-- hive off this nested child-node above the parent -->
   restia volorsin  
</span>
```

### Intended nesting and order of elements (/ nodes)

```
<!-- after xslt -->
<span style="font-family: [Ohne];">restia volorsin</span>
<span style="font-family: qwe;">etu</span>
```

see more [example code](http://pastebin.com/3gRaGuKQ)

Could anyone gave me some tips?

Comment: You should consider showing some code or discussing some methodology so that we can better help you. Consider forming a specific question or stating a problem.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with xml and xslt transformation technics. But it might be helpfull if you could add a little bit information how you are goint to prozess the xml and xslt reformatting (any other tools, languages involved, just the rendering process in the browser..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As easy as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="span[span]">
  <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()[not(self::span)]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="span"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<span style="font-family: [Ohne];">
   <span style="font-family: qwe;">etu</span>
   <!-- hive off this nested child-node above the parent -->
   restia volorsin
</span>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<span style="font-family: [Ohne];"><!-- hive off this nested child-node above the parent -->
   restia volorsin
</span>
<span style="font-family: qwe;">etu</span>
```